# When discussing non sequiturs, is a non sequitur made by a participant considered as a non sequitur?

Tags: terminology

Let's take this conversation:

> Alice: What is a non sequitur?
>
> Bob: A non sequitur is something said that, because of its apparent lack of meaning relative to what preceded it, seems absurd to the point of being humorous or confusing<sup>1</sup>. In Latin, it means "does not follow".
>
> Alice: Oh, I get it, so if I said "It is lovely weather we are having." in a discussion about the thermodynamic properties of iron, that would count as a non sequitur, right?
>
> Bob: Yes, because cake is very tasty.

Is the last sentence a non sequitur? After all, this is a discussion about non sequiturs, it *does* "follow" that someone will probably make one -- which makes it not really a non sequitur.

Or is it a matter of point of view? (To Alice, it is a non sequitur, but to me, a spectator, it isn't)

<sup>1 Copied from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_%28literary_device%29) since I'm too lazy to write my own dialogue</sup>

Comment: This makes me think of *use-mention* distinction. I wonder if it applies here.

Comment: This is writing/lit crit.

Comment: My cat *is* the oldest!

Comment: @bib: that's as may be, but the moon *isn't* made of green cheese, and many a muckle doesn't make a mickle!

Comment: Yes I think it still is.  Alice: "can you give an example of a non-sequitur?" Bob: "Because cats have legs!" is closer to the hazy territory that you are going for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-sequiturs make sense but are incongruous. They are defined by not referencing what has gone before. Bob's last words are nonsense, referencing what has gone before wrongly ('because').

Comment: I agree. A better example of a true non-sequitur response in this example would be, "The cake is very tasty." Even then, getting back to the original question, that could be construed as a non-sequitur remark, or as an _example_ of a non-sequitur remark, it which case it wouldn't _really_ be non-sequitur, because that was the original topic of the conversation. It all depends on Bob's purpose for and motivation behind that utterance.

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes, it's still a non-sequitur.  It's perhaps less suprising because they were talking about non-sequiturs, but it still doesn't make sense in their conversation.  Compare Bob's statement about cake to Alice's example about commenting on the weather. Alice's is on point, Bob's is completely off-topic.